# Generate XML using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have the following PHP code from which I need to generate XML.

```
$hparams["SiteName"]=""; 
$hparams["AccountCode"]=""; 
$hparams["UserName"]='xxxx'; 
$hparams["Password"]='xxxx'; 
$client_header = new SoapHeader('url','AuthenticationData',$hparams,false); 
$cliente = new SoapClient($wsdl); $cliente->__setSoapHeaders(array($client_header)); 
$opta=array(); 
$opta["Search"]["request"]["Origin"]="MAA"; 
$opta["Search"]["request"]["Destination"]="BOM"; 
$opta["Search"]["request"]["DepartureDate"]="2014-05-20T00:00:00"; 
$opta["Search"]["request"]["ReturnDate"]="2014-05-22T00:00:00"; 
$opta["Search"]["request"]["Type"]="OneWay"; 
$opta["Search"]["request"]["CabinClass"]="All";
$opta["Search"]["request"]["PreferredCarrier"]=""; 
$opta["Search"]["request"]["AdultCount"]="1"; 
$opta["Search"]["request"]["ChildCount"]="0"; 
$opta["Search"]["request"]["InfantCount"]="0"; 
$opta["Search"]["request"]["SeniorCount"]="0";
$opta["Search"]["request"]["IsDirectFlight"]="true"; 
$opta["Search"]["request"]["PromotionalPlanType"]="Normal";
$h=array();      
$h= (array)$cliente->__call('Search',$opta);
```

How can I generate an XML of the above variables in PHP ?

The format should be

```
<xml>
<credential>
<Sitename>sitename</Sitename>
<AccountCode>ACC Code</AccountCode>
</credentials>

<Data>
<Origin>MAA</Origin>
<Destination>BOM</Destination>
</Data>
</xml>
```

Any help would be appreciate.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you share url of wsdl?

Comment: Is passing array as parameters doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php 
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
$dom = new DomDocument('1.0');  // making xml

$credentials    = $dom->appendChild($dom->createElement('Credentials'));  // adding root element <credentials>

$sitename       = $credentials->appendChild($dom->createElement('Sitename')); // adding element  <sitename> in <credentials> 
$accountcode    = $credentials->appendChild($dom->createElement('AccountCode')); // adding element  <accountcode> in <credentials> 

$sitename->appendChild($dom->createTextNode('sitename')); // adding text in <sitename> 
$accountcode->appendChild($dom->createTextNode('ACC Code')); // adding text in <accountcode> 

$data           = $dom->appendChild($dom->createElement('Data')); 
$origin         = $data->appendChild($dom->createElement('Origin')); 
$destination    = $data->appendChild($dom->createElement('Destination'));

$origin->appendChild($dom->createTextNode('MAA')); 
$destination->appendChild($dom->createTextNode('BOM')); 

$dom->formatOutput = true; // generating xml

// generating XML as string or file 
$test1 = $dom->saveXML(); 
$dom->save('test1.xml'); 
?>
```

I think you could write loop by yourself ;)
P.S. PHP 5+

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your xml is not well structured. 
It should be like:

```
    <xml>
        <credentials>
            <Sitename>sitename</Sitename>
            <AccountCode>ACC Code</AccountCode>
            <Data>
                <Origin>MAA</Origin>
                <Destination>BOM</Destination>
            </Data>
        </credentials>
<credentials>
    ...
</credentials>
    </xml>
```

> Iterate the obtained result, and by concating , form the needed xml.